# How to make var_dump();die in magento downloadble products

Tags: php, magento

i want to make var_dump();die;  to obtain the model of downloadble product,

i tried to add this method when admin makes click on upload donwadle information 
magento\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\downloadable\catalog\product\links.phtml in _prepareLayout() but the process doesn't work as spected.

```
 protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setChild(
        'upload_button',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')->addData(array(
            'id'      => '',
            'label'   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Upload Files'),
            'type'    => 'button',
            'onclick' => 'Downloadable.massUploadByType(\'links\');Downloadable.massUploadByType(\'linkssample\')'

        ))



    );
    $links=Mage::getModel('downloadable/link')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid));

    var_dump($links);die;
}
```

Comment: What output you get?

Comment: How do you get your "$productid" variable ?? I guess you have a fatal error because of this undefined variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Zend_Debug:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($product->debug())
```

When you try do var_dump a lot of data models, this will run error or slow down your pc. If you use Zend_Debug in place of magento var_dump it will limit data to show but will not bug your computer.

Try it!

If method "$links->debug()" throw error use this directly:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($links)
```

Font: http://www.atwix.com/magento/debugging-hints/